# Java - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.2 (or 2.12.4 or 2.16):test

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build an application using `Maven-3.0.4` and `jdk 1.6.0_45`. In order to successfully build the application, I need to perform six tasks out of which three are success but the fourth one is failing repeatedly.

The tasks (along with the status) are:-

```
[INFO] Eureka! Clinical Analytics ........................ SUCCESS [15.788s]
[INFO] Eureka Common ..................................... SUCCESS [4:45.548s]
[INFO] Eureka WebApp ..................................... SUCCESS [6:46.893s]
[INFO] Eureka Services ................................... FAILURE [8:59.532s]
[INFO] Eureka Protempa ETL ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Eureka EAR ........................................ SKIPPED
```

It requires 'maven-surefire-plugin`in order to succeed at the`Eureka Services` task as certain tests are to be done.

I've tried using `maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.2\2.12.4\2.16` versions of the plugin but the error is always the same and is as follows:-

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.2 (or 2.12.4 or 2.16):test (default-test) on project eureka-services: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/user/eureka-1.8.2/eureka-services/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
```

I am not able to understand what to do now. Please advice.

Note:- I am doing it on terminal as I don't have much knowledge about Eclipse.

Comment: Have a look in 
/home/user/eureka-1.8.2/eureka-services/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.

Comment: I have but I don't know what I have to look for.

Comment: It's likely that there are tests failing. The results of the tests are in the directory specified.

Comment: Before the output you gave, there must be a line telling which tests have failed or are in error. Then in the `surefire-reports` directory, you'll find a text file for each test class with the detailed test output

Comment: @Gorkk yes that's the case.

Answer (score -1):

You have to resolve the tests of Eureka Services package.

You can found the log here /home/user/eureka-1.8.2/eureka-services/target/surefire-reports.